# How to work around Skype 7's notice that a hotkey is "probably" used by another application?

Tags: skype

I've been using a particular hotkey for Focus Skype for years and years. I'm pretty used to it. Then, Skype 7 comes out and tells me this:

[image: The hotkey for Focus Skype is probably used by another application and will be disabled for Skype]

Can I somehow tell Skype to use it anyway?